# Changing output of Forms with Struts+Freemarker

Tags: forms, templates, struts2, struts, freemarker

I'm working on a Website with Struts2 and Freemarker.

Whenever I add form tags such as:

> <@s.form action="foo">
>      <@s.combobox (...)/>

It generates a bunch of html/css/javascript that I don't need.

Is there any way I can specify that no extra elements should be generated or do I really need to go into Freemarker.jar and edit the templates to my liking?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about "themes" in struts2 tags ?
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/why-do-the-form-tags-put-table-tags-around-controls.html
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html